# JSON Schema for XML in openAPI.json

Tags: json, jsonschema, swagger-editor

Following is the JSON schema

```
schema:
  required: true
  title: number
  properties:
  number:
    type: string
    xml:
    name: number
```

Following is the json object which get created in swagger-editor . This is exactly what i want

```
{"number": "string"}
```

The problem is the xml structure which is generated :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<number>
    <number>string</number>
</number>
```

What I want is something like the following :

```
<number>string</number>
```

Comment: The XML structure is generated by what?

Comment: The json schema is part of the openAPI.json file. The XML structure is generated by the swagger, as I import the openAPI.json file

Comment: It sounds like this is a Swagger problem. I would suggest you raise an issue on the appropriate Github repo or make a support request.